# How to pass state from custom component to parent in React Native

Tags: react-native, components, use-state

I'm trying to create a custom Modal component to be reused throughout my app but I'm struggling to manage the state. An example of usage of this modal is to have a button that makes it visible. To me, that would seem to suggest the state of the modal needs to be stored in the parent component, otherwise, there's no way to access the initially false visibility to make it true. However, I'm unsure of how to access the state in the parent component from the child modal. And maybe that's wrong altogether. Seems like storing state in the custom component would be cleaner.

My many attempts have all been somewhere along the lines of the below. Please understand I am omitting a significant amount of what I feel is irrelevant code here. I'm not looking for code troubleshooting, I'm struggling with the concept as a whole.

```js
    import React, { useState } from 'react';
    import { << various components >>, Modal } from 'react-native';
    import CustomModal from << path >>;
    
    export default function App() {
      const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);

      return (
        << screen components >>
        <CustomModal
          visible={modalVisible}
          << etc. >>
        />

        <TouchableOpacity onPress={setModalVisible(true)}>
          <Text>Open Modal</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      );
    }

    << styles, etc. >>
```

So this succeeds in making the modal visible, but I'm not sure how to close it. There's a button on the modal intended to close it, but I can't figure out what the `onPress` should do. I want to access the `modalVisible` state in the parent to call `setModalVisible(false)`, but I can't fathom how to do it.

Am I thinking about this all wrong? I've seen several examples that use 'this' and 'constructor' and 'super' etc. which are things I thought were replaced by hooks and they just confuse me (please go easy on me). I'm also sure you can do it with Redux, but I'm trying to better understand "lifting up state" if I'm even saying it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass as prop for **setModalVisible** in your `CustomModal` component like:

```js
    <CustomModal
      visible = {modalVisible}
      setModal = {setModalVisible(!modalVisible)}
      << etc. >>
    />
```

Then on the closing of your modal call **setModal**.

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Shoaib, thank you so much for your help. I very much appreciate you not getting hung up on the vagueness of my question :)

Comment: No problem sunny :)